# It wants me to report issue, but doesn't tell me what the issue is

Tags: 18.04

[image]

It keeps popping out the notifier, but it doesn't tell me what the issue is, and I see it every time I enter my desktop.

Comment: @K7AAY No, it's in normal mode. That is the problem, I don't know which log file should I see.

Comment: Let's start by collecting the output of dmesg http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html  . Save it, click [edit[ and add that to your original post. Then, reboot into Recovery Mode and see if the problem recurs, then add that to your original post. Please do not reply with a Comment as you did above; all your additions to the question should go in the question